# express render security on front-end

Tags: node.js, express

Say I have the following view

```
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    let data = await Data.findOne({ field: "doesnt matter" })
    // data returns a mongoose obj i.e  {_id: ... , __v: ...}
    res.render('dataPage', { info: data });
})
```

Is it safe to pass a mongoose object directly to res.render()? I am worried that a user on the front end will be able to access the information in the info object that is coming from the render method.

Comment: The translation from the info object to the HTML page happens in the `dataPage` view on the server. Those parts of the info object that are not evaluated during this translation will not be visible to the user. But surely the user is meant to see some of the information, so I'm not sure I understand your question correctly.